# Slot Machine win chance way too high

Tags: math, lua, statistics

I am creating a slot machine with a return rate of about 95%. But I feel like I'm winning way too often. Can anyone confirm this? The slot machine has 3 spinners (reels) with 4 different symbols each. The chance of winning is supposed to be:

> 3x Symbol[1] : 23.6% chance (50% at first spinner, 80% second, 59% third)
>
> 3x Symbol[2] : 9.45% chance (25% at first spinner, 70% second, 54% third)
>
> 3x Symbol[3] : 1.89% chance (15% at first spinner, 60% second, 21% third)
>
> 3x Symbol[4] : 0.19% chance (10% at first spinner, 50% second, 3.8% third)

```
local symbol = {} 
symbol[1] = {0.5, 0.8, 0.59}
symbol[2] = {0.5, 0.7, 0.54} 
symbol[3] = {0.6, 0.6, 0.21} 
symbol[4] = {1, 0.5, 0.038}

function chance(x) 
    if math.random() <= x then 
        return true
    end 
end

-- FIRST SPINNER
for i = 1, 4 do 
    if chance(symbol[i][1]) then
        stop[1] = symbol[i] 
        break
    end
end

-- SECOND SPINNER
for i = 1, 4 do 
    if stop[1] == symbol[i] then
        if chance(symbol[i][2]) then
            stop[2] = symbol[i]
        else
            -- stop[3] = some random symbol that is not equal to stop[1]
        end
        break
    end
end 

-- THIRD SPINNER
for i = 1, 4 do 
    if stop[1] == symbol[i] and stop[2] == symbol[i] then
        if chance(symbol[i][3]) then
            stop[3] = symbol[i]
        else
            -- stop[3] = some random symbol that is not equal to stop[2]
        end 
    end
end
        
if stop[3] == nil then
    -- stop[3] = some random symbol that is not equal to stop[2]
end

-- WIN SCRIPT
if stop[1] == stop[2] and stop[2] == stop[3] then
   -- reward player
end
```

Comment: `symbol[4] = {1, 0.5..` shouldn't it be `0.1`?

Comment: @hjpotter92 - Should not.  See "FIRST SPINNER" section.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
local symbol = {}
symbol[1] = {0.5, 0.8, 0.59}
symbol[2] = {0.5, 0.7, 0.54}
symbol[3] = {0.6, 0.6, 0.21}
symbol[4] = {1, 0.5, 0.038}

function chance(x)
   return math.random() <= x
end

-- FIRST SPINNER
for _, sym in ipairs(symbol) do
   stop[1] = sym
   if chance(sym[1]) then break end
end

-- SECOND SPINNER
if chance(stop[1][2]) then
   stop[2] = stop[1]
   -- THIRD SPINNER
   if chance(stop[1][3]) then
      stop[3] = stop[1]
   else
      -- stop[3] = some random symbol that is not equal to stop[1]
      repeat
         stop[3] = symbol[math.random(4)]
      until stop[3] ~= stop[1]
   end
else
   -- stop[2], stop[3] = some random symbols, not both equal to stop[1]
   repeat
      stop[2] = symbol[math.random(4)]
      stop[3] = symbol[math.random(4)]
   until stop[2] ~= stop[1] or stop[3] ~= stop[1]
end

-- WIN SCRIPT
if stop[1] == stop[2] and stop[2] == stop[3] then
   -- reward player
end
```